# SQL Month selection with two parameters

Tags: mysql, time, frequency

In a table I have a column called 'service_time' which is the start date of a service, and another column 'times_year' which is how many times per year the service shall be done.

The problem I have is how I should select the rows when -> (thisMonth == service_time (month)) OR (thisMonth == service_time (month) + 12/times_year) 
The tricky part that I cannot solve is how should I do this if the 'times_year' is a value between 1-4? Without making 4 different OR's??

So should it be something of a loop decided by the 'times_year' instead of doing a OR query to check all 4 OR's every single time even if the 'times_year' isn't 4?

UPDATE:

Well I need help how to do a loop in the sql query statement wich will only select if the 'month' is correct, so basiclly now its the '08' and if the service_time is set to 2015-03-01 (day doesnt matter) it shall do a check with the times_year to check if 2015-03-01 shall be having a service > 2015-03 + 12/4(as an example) then 2015-06, 2015-09, 2015-12, 2016-03 Then no dont select and so on...
I could do this in PHP but it will not be efficent in the longer term

Comment: can you explain better?

Comment: Updated.. if that explains it better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you don't have `times_year` values like 5, 11, and so forth.  That will get a little nasty to work out. Values like 1,2,3,4,6,12 are good.

You can determine the next service time after the start time like this in MySQL

```
service_time + INTERVAL (12 DIV times_year) MONTH
```

Similarly, the third service time after the start time will work like this.

```
service_time + INTERVAL 3*(12 DIV times_year) MONTH
```

Maybe your business rules call for service to be due on or before the last calendar day of each month. You can display that like so.

```
LAST_DAY(service_time + INTERVAL 3*(12 DIV times_year) MONTH)
```

Finally, you may wish to display the next service due date after today (after `CURDATE()`) How do you do that?

First, it has been this many months since the first service time:

```
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, service_time, CURDATE())
```

Next, you want to know how many service intervals that covers.  Easy:

```
  times_year * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, service_time, CURDATE()) / 12.0
```

Next, you want the next highest service interval number:

```
  CEIL(times_year * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), service_time) / 12.0)
```

Finally, plug that into the next-service-time function:

```
service_time + INTERVAL 
     CEIL(times_year * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, service_time, CURDATE()) / 12.0)*
     (12 DIV times_year) MONTH
```

It's a long formula, but it works.

Finally, you can use this WHERE clause to find out all the services due before the end of the present month.

```
WHERE LAST_DAY(service_time + INTERVAL 
      CEIL(times_year * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, service_time, CURDATE()) / 12.0)*
      (12 DIV times_year) MONTH) <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Ollie, and thank you for explain why and how it works! :)